# Acess to this from subobject in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How do I get access to the properties or method of the main object, from sub-obiect level two (sub3). If possible I would like to avoid solutions chaining return this.

```
Obj = function () {};
Obj.prototype = {
    name: 'name',
    main: function(){
        console.log(this.name);
    },
    subobject: {
        sub2: function () {
            console.log(this);
        },

        sub3: function () {
            console.log(this.name);  // How access to Obj.name ??
        }

    }
}
o = new Obj();
o.main(); // return name
o.subobject.sub2(); // return subobject
o.subobject.sub3(); // return undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current syntax, you can't. Because for `sub2` and `sub3`, the `this` variable is `Obj.prototype.subobject`.

You have multiple choice:

- The obvious one: don't use a suboject.
- Create `subobject`, `sub2` and `sub3` in the constructor

  ```
  Obj = function() {
      var self = this;

      this.subobject = {
          sub1: function() { console.log(self); }
      }
  }
  ```
- Use `bind` at each call:

  ```
  o.subobject.sub2.bind(o)();
  ```