# Using the 'this' value inside an object

Tags: javascript

Basicly I'm trying to add an object with my own functions inside the object.prototype.

```
Object.prototype.personalTest = {
  sum: function () {
    return this.something + this.other;
  }
};
var numbers = {
  something: 1,
  other: 2
};
console.log(numbers.personalTest.sum());
```

Problem is I can't get the value from the original object. The 'this' keyword uses my object as the 'this'.

How can I change the value of the 'this' or pass it to the object?

**Edit**
I did this and it kind of worked but not as I wanted

```
var personalAccess = function () {
  var self = this;
  this.PersonalTools = {
    sum: function () {
      return self.something + self.other;
    },
    minus: function () {
      return self.something - self.other;
    }
  };
};
Object.prototype.personalTest = personalAccess;
var numbers = {
  something: 1,
  other: 2
};
console.log(numbers.personalTest());
```

The objects aren't part of the prototype anymore but that's not a problem. 
The problem is that for each variable i have to build the objects using the function.

```
console.log(numbers.personalTest());
```

**..........Solution...........**

I ended up learning a bit more tricks on javascript and used **factory functions** to solve my issue.

```
(function () {
var myTools = function () {
    var self = this;
    var tools = {
      sum: self.first + self.second
    };
    return tools;
  };
  Object.prototype.MyTools = myTools;
}());
```

Comment: Try to check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Acess to this from subobject in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527509/acess-to-this-from-subobject-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code:

```
Object.prototype.personalTest = {
  sum: function () {
    return this.something + this.other;
  }
};
```

adds a new property named `personalTest` to each object you create.

This property is an object itself, having one property, `sum`, that is a function. Inside the `sum()` function, `this` refers to this object whose property `sum()` is (i.e. the object you create and store in `Object.prototype.personalTest`).

You can let `sum` access the properties of `numbers` by invoking it this way:

```
var numbers = {
  something: 1,
  other: 2
};

console.log(numbers.personalTest.sum.call(numbers));
```

This way, the function `sum()` (accessible only through the property `personalTest.sum` of any object) is invoked using `numbers` as `this`.

Read more about [`Function.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you.
But is there a way that i can use the call function without needing to write it every time?
I want to keep just numbers.personalTest.sum()
Is it possible?

Comment: @AnthonyWhite can you check my answer.  An alternative is using setters and getters.

Comment: You can, as well, add `sum()` directly as a property of `Object.prototype` and invoke it as `numbers.sum()`.

Comment: @AnthonyWhite that last comment from axiac is a good alternative.

Comment: Thing is I want something like a personal "submenu" of my own functions. That's why I'm looking for something like: variable.myPersonalFunctions.function1

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you're thinking that the function `sum` declared within `personalTest` will have access to any attributes outside from it.  The scope of function `sum` is the object `personalTest`.

An alternative, is either binding that object `numbers` to the function `sum` or executing the function `call` passing the object `numbers`.

```
numbers.personalTest.sum.bind(numbers)();
numbers.personalTest.sum.call(numbers);
```

```js
Object.prototype.personalTest = {
  sum: function () {  
    return this.something + this.other;
  }
};

var numbers = {
  something: 1,
  other: 2
};


console.log(numbers.personalTest.sum.bind(numbers)());
console.log(numbers.personalTest.sum.call(numbers));
```

Or, you can assign those values to `personalTest` to make them accesible from the function `sum`.

```js
Object.prototype.personalTest = {
  sum: function () {  
    return this.something + this.other;
  }
};

var numbers = {
  something: 1,
  other: 2
};

Object.assign(numbers.personalTest, numbers);
console.log(numbers.personalTest.sum());
```

Another alternative, is creating setters and getters to automatically set the necessary attributes to `personalTest`:

```js
Object.prototype.personalTest = {
  sum: function () {  
    return this.something + this.other;
  }
};

var numbers = {
  set something(s) {
    this.thing = this.personalTest.something = s;
  },
  get something() {
    return this.thing;
  },
  set other(s) {
    this.o = this.personalTest.other = s;
  },
  get other() {
    return this.o;
  }
};

numbers.something = 1
numbers.other = 2

console.log(numbers.personalTest.sum());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That is way to complicated for me hahah.
Thing is I want something like a personal "submenu" of my own functions. 
That's why I'm looking for something like:

variable.myPersonalFunctions.function1

Comment: @AnthonyWhite got it, well the alternative is bind those attributes to the function `sum`. `:)`

Comment: I'm going to try that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers.personalTest.sum.call(numbers)
```

Comment: Please add somes explanations editing your answer, avoid code only answer

Comment: The call() method calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided individually.

Comment: Make a readable answer for people https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer not for me ;) that's why I precised editing the answer